# .Net ; Read stable weight from RS232

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework

I have a small application that can read weigh scale weights continuously.

I want users to only capture when the weight stabilizes for about 3 seconds.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the received values with there timestamps in a queue and then calculate the min, max and average over the last three seconds.

First create a class to hold the values and the timestamp, for example called measure.

Then create another class with a qqeue of measure. Implement functions for adding a measure to the class internal queue and to calculate the min,max and average for a timespan. The final function can then use min, max and average to say if the last measure is near enough to the average within a time span.

Instead of a queue you may use a data table and then use sql commands to get that scalars for min, max and average.

If the values are delivered with a constant interval in between, you can avoid the timespan parts and only calculate over the last x values. For example if the scale delivers a new value every 0.5 second, you will have 6 values for the last three seconds.

A FIFO will store the values (use an array with custom add function or a queue). To know if the last values are stable, you need to know what is the min, max and average over the last measures. That enables you to decide if the last value is near the average or if the diff to min and max is too large.

Ie measures:

3 4 8 2 5 4 gives min=2, max=8, avg=4.3. The last val is near to avg but far from max

5 4 6 4 5 5 gives min=4, max=6, avg=4.9, The last value is near min, max and avg. That seems to be a good last measure.